# MetroPanel.Paint does not paint

Tags: c#, draw, metroframework

I have a MetroPanel on which I want to draw a line across. The panel name is panelSearch and the Paint event is like this:

```cs
private void panelSearch_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            Pens.Red,
            0,
            panelSearch.Size.Height,
            panelSearch.Size.Width,
           0
        );
}
```

The line does not show, if I switch to a regular panle then I can see the line. I guess this has something to do with the framework. Do you know how I can get to draw on a MetroPanel?

Comment: If you are to paint it yourself like you are right now there is no reason to use a custom control.

Comment: I do not agree....I want to use the Metro style but still add my own line in order to visually separate items

Comment: I solved by using a regular Panel and making it transparent. Bottom line here is that there is no option to draw on MetroPanel, am I correct?

Comment: Never tried drawing with the event so i cannot tell. But for sure if you were to derive your own control from the metro panel and `override` the `onpaint` then you certainly can.